# Why phpmyadmin is not exporting all the rows?

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin, mysql

I am trying to export my wp_posts table which has more than 11000 posts in it, and the table rows are more than 5500 and also the table size is more than 15MB. I tried exporting the table but it do not export all the rows, it just export 3k-4k posts only.

Can anyone tell me the reason behind it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be because of a timeout error, where your server is ending the export before it is finished. One solution is to export the DB piecemeal (a few tables at a time), or to reconfigure your server to allow for longer timeout limit.  Try googleing "phpmyadmin timeout export".

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the max_execution_time inside PHP? Maybe the export needs some time!?
It might also be possible, that you'll run into a memory limit.

Therefore the easiest and fastest way would be to check your server error log (the one running PHPMyAdmin) for any max_execution_time or memory_limit errors